# I'm getting an error in Xcode when I want to add Google Maps

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, google-maps, cocoa-touch

Use of undeclared identifier 'AIRGoogleMapOverlay'

Use of undeclared identifier 'overlay'

```
#import "AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager.h"
#import "AIRGoogleMapOverlay.h"

@interface AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager()

@end

@implementation AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  AIRGoogleMapOverlay * overlay = [AIRGoogleMapOverlay new];
  overlay.bridge = self.bridge;
  return overlay;
}


RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(bounds, boundsRect, NSArray)
RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(image, imageSrc, NSString)

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code not image for users to work on your problem...

Comment: If you are using pods file, after integrating close Xcode and reopen  project.xcworkspace not project.xcodeproj

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you said

Comment: To integrate google maps what you used

Comment: I use pods.....

Comment: After integrating are you opened project.xcworkspace or project.xcodeproj, Which one?

Comment: I opened project.xcodeproj

Answer (score 3):

in Build Phases > Compile Sources add new compiler flag to each "*AirGoogleMap" file

```
-DHAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1
```

see attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: actually correction - if the above doesn't help try to REMOVE all the files as per my screenshot from "Compile Sources" list [only AirGoogleMaps files though]

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem. Close your Xcode completely and reopen your project with project.xcworkspace. Because when you create pod file one more file will be created with the name of yourprojectname.xcworkspace. Now you need to open this project.xcworkspace not project.xcodeproj

See the difference between two files in below screen shot

[image]

Open red colour file

Comment: as you said, close xcode and open the project.xcworkspace file and run again. But I got the same mistake again.

Comment: Once check and follow these steps https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Comment: IF you properly integrated maps, remove derived data and run again.

Comment: I created a different project and tried all the steps again and I got the same error again.